# Need table to break in between

Tags: tables, longtable, booktabs

I have quite a long table and it overlaps two pages. I dont want it in landscape. I need the table to be displayed in portrait in my document. I've come across similar questions and implemented the suggestions like using longtable and \* to keep the midrule together, but unfortunately they haven't worked for me. The Name column in quite big, and the other three are just numerical columns. I need a table that is readable as its quite cluttered. I'm new to Latex, and I'd appreciate any advice I can get.

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{array}                                                                       
\begin{document} 
\begingroup
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
        \begin{table}
        \caption{Results from Analysis}
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.6\textwidth-3\tabcolsep}p{0.27\textwidth-3\tabcolsep}p{0.23\textwidth-3\tabcolsep}p{0.25\textwidth-3\tabcolsep}} 
        \toprule
        Name & Significance & Group A & GroupB  \\
        \midrule
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 6.16E-05 & 35 & 18\\

       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX9 & 4.91E-04 & 25 & 12\\

       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 4.91E-04 & 25 & 12\\

      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.31E-03 & 20 & 9\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.55E-03 & 23 & 12\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 2.00E-03 & 17 & 7\\

        pXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXe & 2.41E-03 & 13 & 4\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 3.81E-03 & 8 & 1\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 4.77E-03 & 12 & 4\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 7.65E-03 & 19 & 11\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX& 1.13E-02 & 13 & 6\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.16E-02 & 23 & 16\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX& 1.20E-02 & 14 & 7\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.22E-02 & 21 & 14\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.26E-02 & 30 & 24\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (C5) & 1.26E-02 & 19 & 12\\

        eXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.54E-02 & 9 & 3\\

        2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.76E-02 & 10 & 4\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  & 1.92E-02 & 6 & 1\\

       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.92E-02 & 6 & 1\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.92E-02 & 6 & 1\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 2.55E-02 & 7 & 2\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 2.55E-02 & 7 & 2\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 2.62E-02 & 4 & 0\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 2.62E-02 & 4 & 0\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 2.62E-02 & 4 & 0\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 27 & 23\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX* & 3.25E-02 & 9 & 4\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 3.31E-02 & 16 & 11\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0 & 3.37E-02 & 24 & 20\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 3.47E-02 & 14 & 9\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 3.52E-02 & 13 & 8\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 3.53E-02 & 12 & 7\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 4.19E-02 & 5 & 1\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 4.19E-02 & 5 & 1\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
        \endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Longtable is the way to go, but you have to remove the table environment.

Comment: The width is fine, its the length that I have a problem with. I want it to stop in the middle and I used the \\\* but it didnt work for me.

Comment: Well, the longtable approach works for me. So what have you tried?

Comment: @TeXnician It breaks in the middle and the next page carries on with the header?

Comment: Yes, of course. That's what longtable is supposed to do. I just  removed your table environment, switched to longtable, moved the caption to the correct position and added `\endhead` (as is stated in the docs).

Comment: There's too much whitespace in the entire table, it doesnt help.

Comment: It's easier for us to help you, if you could remove all unnecessary packages (including fonts) and only keep the needed ones. That way the code will be a MWE we can work with.

Comment: @TeXnician Sorry about that. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your code shows several errors.

For example you called package `longtable`, but you did not use it in the code.  See the following MWE for that.

To be able to calculate column length with `{p{0.6\textwidth-3\tabcolsep}` you need to call package `calc`. See the following MWE.

To be able to break the line in your name column you need to add blanks or allow hyphenations  (`\-`) of names like this:

```
XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX      & 6.16E-05 & 35 & 18\\
XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX9     & 4.91E-04 & 25 & 12\\
XXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     & 4.91E-04 & 25 & 12\\
XXXXXXXX\-XXXXXXXX\-XXXXXX\-XXXXXXXXX\-XXXXXXX & 1.31E-03 & 20 & 9\\
```

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}   % <============== ?????????
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  % <============== ?????????
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{calc}  % <==================================================


\begin{document} 
\begingroup
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}

  \begin{longtable}{p{0.6\textwidth-3\tabcolsep}p{0.27\textwidth-3\tabcolsep}p{0.23\textwidth-3\tabcolsep}p{0.25\textwidth-3\tabcolsep}} 
  \caption{Results from Analysis}\\
  \toprule
  Name & Significance & GroupA & GroupB  \\
  \midrule
\endfirsthead % <===============================================
  \toprule
  Name & Significance & GroupA & GroupB  \\
  \midrule
\endhead % <===============================================
XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX      & 6.16E-05 & 35 & 18\\
XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX9     & 4.91E-04 & 25 & 12\\
XXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     & 4.91E-04 & 25 & 12\\
XXXXXXXX\-XXXXXXXX\-XXXXXX\-XXXXXXXXX\-XXXXXXX & 1.31E-03 & 20 & 9\\

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.55E-03 & 23 & 12\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 2.00E-03 & 17 & 7\\
        pXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXe & 2.41E-03 & 13 & 4\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 3.81E-03 & 8 & 1\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 4.77E-03 & 12 & 4\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 7.65E-03 & 19 & 11\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX& 1.13E-02 & 13 & 6\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.16E-02 & 23 & 16\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX& 1.20E-02 & 14 & 7\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.22E-02 & 21 & 14\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.26E-02 & 30 & 24\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (C5) & 1.26E-02 & 19 & 12\\
        eXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.54E-02 & 9 & 3\\
        2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.76E-02 & 10 & 4\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  & 1.92E-02 & 6 & 1\\
       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.92E-02 & 6 & 1\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 1.92E-02 & 6 & 1\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 2.55E-02 & 7 & 2\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 2.55E-02 & 7 & 2\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 2.62E-02 & 4 & 0\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 2.62E-02 & 4 & 0\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 2.62E-02 & 4 & 0\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 27 & 23\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX* & 3.25E-02 & 9 & 4\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 3.31E-02 & 16 & 11\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0 & 3.37E-02 & 24 & 20\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 3.47E-02 & 14 & 9\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 3.52E-02 & 13 & 8\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 3.53E-02 & 12 & 7\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 4.19E-02 & 5 & 1\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX & 4.19E-02 & 5 & 1\\
  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

resulting in the first page:

[image: first page]